# May an npm update cause malfunciton or breakdown?

Tags: node.js, npm

I've a trouble with the frontend part of an application. Code build correctly in our local machines. In production build is broken (gulp build fails). npm and node versions are different locally and remotely.

Local versions:

```
prompt> npm -v
3.10.8
prompt> node -v
v6.9.1
```

Remote versions:

```
prompt> npm -v
3.9.5
prompt> node -v
v6.2.2
```

Actually build fails due to strange reason. Strange just because all works fine locall.

```
warning Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/user/admin.example.com/.tmp/serve/styles/kendo.common.min.css.map'
warning at Error (native)
warning at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:634:18)
warning at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:502:33)
warning at fromSource (/home/user/admin.example.com/node_modules/clean-css/lib/utils/input-source-map-tracker.js:84:30)
warning at InputSourceMapStore.track (/home/user/admin.example.com/node_modules/clean-css/lib/utils/input-source-map-tracker.js:237:5)
warning at Object.whenDone (/home/user/admin.example.com/node_modules/clean-css/lib/clean.js:145:44)
warning at processNext (/home/user/admin.example.com/node_modules/clean-css/lib/imports/inliner.js:105:13)
warning at importFrom (/home/forge/admin.example.com/node_modules/clean-css/lib/imports/inliner.js:79:10)
warning at ImportInliner.process (/home/forge/admin.example.com/node_modules/clean-css/lib/imports/inliner.js:38:10)
warning at /home/forge/admin.example.com/node_modules/clean-css/lib/clean.js:120:41
warning at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
warning at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
execute gulp build
```

Comment: do you use different Operating Systems?

Comment: absolutely: locally I've MacOsX. Remotely Ubuntu.

Comment: Does the path `/home/ …  /kendo.common.min.css.map` exist?
Have you tried running `sudo npm install` on the remote?
In general: Version differences can indeed affect application stability. It may also be due to a non-existing or faulty dependency (see `package.json` for that). If need be, try to replicate the versions as closely as possible, and downgrade the local version to the server's version. Also replicate the environment, for instance by using VirtualBox with the same OS and Node version for testing.

Comment: nope: not exists.

Comment: maybe there is a cache system? Something that look for some old files?

Comment: I'd start looking into the first error. Why does said file not exist? How is it generated, or do you have to generate it yourself? Can you update it on the server remotely to do so? Often fixing the first error may fix subsequent errors (but not always).